# How to call root folder php file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I used one custom module to import csv files for product and attributes.
This file is placed on the root folder of magento.

To run this file, I have to go to URL and write manually, like localhost/magento/test.php

So I have to create for that one module from backend or system/configuration, that has import button and call this file directly.

But that test.php file has an html code that browses the file, and also have two options like Update Or Skip, and that is important for importing product.

So how can I do this?

Call this file in backend?

Below is the file code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
$count = 0;
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        $csvFile = $_REQUEST['csv_file'];
        $check_sku = $_REQUEST['sku_check'];
        //echo $check_sku;die('ankit');
        if(!empty($csvFile)){
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        $firstRow = true;
        $aData = array();
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
          $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        $temparr = array();
        for($x=1;$x<count($line_of_text);$x++) {
            for($z=0;$z<count($line_of_text[$x]);$z++) {
                if(!in_array($line_of_text[$x][$z],$temparr[$line_of_text[0][$z]]))
                    $temparr[$line_of_text[0][$z]][] = $line_of_text[$x][$z];
            }
        }
        foreach($temparr as $key => $att_value){
            /* Below Condition for Check CSV Header and Add Attribute code Begin */
            if($key == 'Manufacturer / Brand'){
                $attr_code = 'manufacturer';
            }else if($key == 'Size'){
                $attr_code = 'size';
            }else if($key == 'Tread Pattern / Type'){
                $attr_code = 'tread_pattern';
            }else if($key == 'Industry / TRA Code'){
                $attr_code = 'industry_code';
            }else if($key == 'Ply Rating / Star Rating'){
                $attr_code = 'ply_rating';
            }else if($key == 'Compound'){
                $attr_code = 'compound';
            }else if($key == 'New / Used'){
                $attr_code = 'condition';
            }else if($key == 'Article Number'){
                $attr_code = 'article_number';
            }else if($key == 'Equipment Model'){
                $attr_code = 'equipment_model';
            }else if($key == 'Equipment Type'){
                $attr_code = 'equipment_type';
            }else if($key == 'OTD (32ND / mm)'){
                $attr_code = 'otd32';
            }else if($key == 'Overall Diameter (inch / mm)'){
                $attr_code = 'overall_diameter';
            }else if($key == 'Overall Width (inch / mm)'){
                $attr_code = 'overall_width';
            }else{
                $attr_code = '';
            }
            /* End Attribute Condition */
            $att_value_arr = $att_value;
            foreach($att_value_arr as $sku => $color) {     
                $optionId =  false;
                $attributeCode =  $attr_code;
                if ($color != '') {
                    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
                    if ($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
                        $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                                ->setAttribute($attribute)
                                ->getAllOptions(false);
                        $_existValue = false;
                        foreach ($options as $option){
                            if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                                $_existValue = true;
                                $optionId = $option['value'];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!$_existValue) {
                            $option = array('value' => array('option' => array($color)));
                            $attribute->setData('option', $option);
                            $attribute->save();
                            $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                                    ->setAttribute($attribute)
                                    ->getAllOptions(false);
                            foreach ($options as $option) {
                                if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                                    $optionId = $option['value'];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($line_of_text);die(); exit(); */

        /************************* Below Code for IMPORT a Product Begin ***************************/
        function getUniqueCode($length = "")
        {
            $code = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            if ($length != "") return substr($code, 0, $length);
            else return $code;
        }
        /********************** Below Code is check if SKU is exist or not Below *******************/
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->load();
            // $arr_sku ARRAY For Get All Product SKU
            $arr_sku = array();
            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
                $arr_sku[] = $_product->getSku();
            }


        /********************** Below Code is check if SKU is exist or not End ********************/
        array_shift($line_of_text);     
        $inc= 1;
        $data = array();
        $skip_arr = array();
        foreach($line_of_text as $csv_pro){
            $cat_name = substr($csv_pro[0], 0, 3);
            $pro_name = substr($csv_pro[22], 0, 3);
            $csv_sku = $cat_name.'-'.$pro_name.'-'.$inc;

            /* Magento Required Fields Begin */
            $price = $csv_pro[18];
            $name = $csv_pro[22];
            $description = $csv_pro[23];
            $short_description = $csv_pro[24];
            $qty = $csv_pro[9];
            if(!empty($name)){$pro_name = $name;}else{$pro_name = 'otr';}
            if(!empty($price)){$reg_price = $price;}else{$reg_price = 10;}
            if(!empty($description)){$pro_description = $description;}else{$pro_description = 'No Desc';}
            if(!empty($short_description)){$pro_shor_description = $short_description;}else{$pro_shor_description = 'No Short Desc';}
            if(!empty($qty)){$pro_qty = $qty;}else{$pro_qty = 10;}
            /* Magento Required Fields End */

            $check_sku_is_found = in_array($csv_sku, $arr_sku);
            if($check_sku_is_found == 1){
                if($check_sku == 'update'){
                    $data[] = array(
                        'sku' => $csv_sku,
                        '_type' => 'simple',
                        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
                        '_product_websites' => 'base',
                        '_category' => $csv_pro[0],
                        'name' => $pro_name,        
                        'price' => $reg_price,      
                        'description' => $pro_description,
                        'short_description' => $pro_shor_description,
                        'meta_title' => $csv_pro[10],
                        'meta_description' => $csv_pro[11],
                        'meta_keyword' => 'Default',
                        'weight' => $csv_pro[12],
                        'status' => 1,
                        'visibility' => 4,
                        'tax_class_id' => 2,
                        'qty' => $pro_qty,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'enable_googlecheckout' => '1',
                        'gift_message_available' => '0',
                        'url_key' => '',
                        'manufacturer' => $csv_pro[1],
                        'size' =>$csv_pro[2],
                        'tread_pattern' =>$csv_pro[3],
                        'industry_code' =>$csv_pro[4],
                        'ply_rating' =>$csv_pro[5],
                        'compound' =>$csv_pro[6],
                        'condition' =>$csv_pro[7],
                        'otd32' =>$csv_pro[13],
                        'overall_diameter' =>$csv_pro[14],
                        'overall_width' =>$csv_pro[15],
                        'article_number' =>$csv_pro[17],
                        'equipment_model' =>$csv_pro[19],
                        'equipment_type' =>$csv_pro[20],
                    );
                    $time = microtime(true);
                    try {
                        /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */                       

                        $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
                        $import->processProductImport($data);


                    /* import image begin  */
                    /* ankit code begin */
                    $productid=$csv_sku; // Product id of that product which image you want to update
                    //for remove existing Images
                    $loadpro= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$csv_sku);
                    $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");                  
                    $mediaApiItems = $mediaApi->items($loadpro->getId());                   
                    //print_r($mediaApiItems);die();
                    foreach($mediaApiItems as $item) {
                        $datatemp = $mediaApi->remove($loadpro->getId(), $item['file']);                        
                    }
                    $loadpro->save(); //before adding need to save product
                    /* ankit code end */ 
                    //for add new images
                    //$loadpro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$csv_sku);
                    //$loadpro->addImageToMediaGallery($loadpro, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), true, false);

                    $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';
                    $productsData = array($csv_pro[25]);
                    //print_r($productsData);
                    $productSKU = $csv_sku;
                    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
                        foreach($productsData as $fileName){
                        $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;               
                            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                                $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
                                $ourProduct->save();
                                echo "Image Uploaded ";
                            } 
                        }
                    /* import image end  */
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
                    } 


                }else{
                    $skip_arr[] = $csv_sku;
                }
            }else{
                //echo "SKU Not Match So Import Product...";
                $data[] = array(
                        'sku' => $csv_sku,
                        '_type' => 'simple',
                        '_attribute_set' => 'Default',
                        '_product_websites' => 'base',
                        '_category' => $csv_pro[0],
                        'name' => $pro_name,        
                        'price' => $reg_price,      
                        'description' => $pro_description,
                        'short_description' => $pro_shor_description,
                        'meta_title' => $csv_pro[10],
                        'meta_description' => $csv_pro[11],
                        'meta_keyword' => 'Default',
                        'weight' => $csv_pro[12],
                        'status' => 1,
                        'visibility' => 4,
                        'tax_class_id' => 2,
                        'qty' => $pro_qty,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'enable_googlecheckout' => '1',
                        'gift_message_available' => '0',
                        'url_key' => '',
                        'manufacturer' => $csv_pro[1],
                        'size' =>$csv_pro[2],
                        'tread_pattern' =>$csv_pro[3],
                        'industry_code' =>$csv_pro[4],
                        'ply_rating' =>$csv_pro[5],
                        'compound' =>$csv_pro[6],
                        'condition' =>$csv_pro[7],
                        'otd32' =>$csv_pro[13],
                        'overall_diameter' =>$csv_pro[14],
                        'overall_width' =>$csv_pro[15],
                        'article_number' =>$csv_pro[17],
                        'equipment_model' =>$csv_pro[19],
                        'equipment_type' =>$csv_pro[20],
                    );

                    $time = microtime(true);
                    try {
                        /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
                        $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
                        $import->processProductImport($data);

                        /* Image Upload Code............. */
                        $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';
                        $productsData = array($csv_pro[25]);
                        $productSKU = $csv_sku;
                        $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);

                        foreach($productsData as $fileName){
                            $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;               
                                if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                                    $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                                    $ourProduct->save();
                                    echo "Image Uploaded ";
                                } 
                            }  

                    /* Image Upload Code............. */

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        //print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
                    }
            }
            $inc++;
        }   
            print_r($skip_arr);
            $query_time = 'Elapsed time: ' . round(microtime(true) - $time, 2) . 's' . "\n";
            $suc_err = "Product Import Successfully !!  ".$query_time;


        /************************* Below Code for IMPORT a Product End *****************************/
    }else{
        $msg_err = "Please Select CSV file";
    }
//print_r($temparr);
fclose($file_handle);
}
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
    if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        ?>
        <div class="csv_import">
            <div class="csv_wrapper">
            <center>
                <h3>Upload Your Product CSV</h3>
                <span style="color:red !important;"><?php if (isset($msg_err)) echo $msg_err; ?>
                <span style="color:green !important;"><?php if (isset($suc_err)) echo $suc_err; ?>
            </center>
            <div class="csv_import_form">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="file" accept=".csv" name="csv_file"></input>
                    <label>If SKU is Found ? :</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="rad_box" name="sku_check" value="update" checked>Update
                    <input type="radio" class="rad_box" name="sku_check" value="skip"> Skip<br>
                    <input class="btn default" type="submit" name="submit" value="IMPORT"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else{ ?>
        <div class="csv_import_form">
            <h1>Admin User is Not Login</h1>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:#222D3F;
}
.csv_import{width:100%;height:100%;color:#fff;}
.btn {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  margin-top:15px;
}
.default {background-color: #e7e7e7; color: black;} /* Gray */
.default:hover {background: #ddd;}
.csv_import_form {
  width: 38%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 2%;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.csv_wrapper {
  padding: 16% 0;
}
form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can use, magento structure by writing this as a module(with controller, phtml and system.xml. In system.xml you can directly assign the controller to the menu).

Comment: I agree, using .php files in your webroot (especially when naming them test.php) makes you very vulnerable to hackers.